# How to conditional render in Chakra UI?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chakra-ui

I'm rendering two Chakra UI components based in a variable loading:

```js
{loading ? (<Spinner>) : (<Text color={useColorModeValue('gray.800', 'gray.400')>Hi</Text) }
```

But the IDE is warning me about this:
`ESLint: React Hook "useColorModeValue" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.`

How should I render those components? useColorModeValue is a hook

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`useColorModeValue` is a React hook, so it can't be conditionally called, it is breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Using a ternary is a way to conditionally call it. The hook must be called each and every render cycle.

> ### Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.**
> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.

Pull the `useColorModeValue` out into the body of the function component and save the returned color value to be passed later to the `Text` component.

```
const color = useColorModeValue('gray.800', 'gray.400');

...

{loading ? <Spinner> : <Text color={color}>Hi</Text>}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally render a property within a Chakra UI component by creating a constant that takes a value and returns the desired property string based on defined conditions. This example was made using React.

```
const colorChange = (value) => {
    let color
    if (value >= 0){
        color = "green"
    } else {
        color = "red"
    }
    return color
  }

<Text color={colorChange(value)}>
```

I googled the title exactly when trying to solve this issue, and found no resources. So I'm hoping this response can help someone who's ran into this same issue. Cheers!